# Связь JavaFX программы с интернетом приводит к зависанию сцены

Tags: javafx

Есть сцена апдейтера, она зависает на время обращения программы к данным с сервера. Например, получаю результат работы php файла:

```
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(u.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        str.append(inputLine);
    in.close();
```

Пока получаются данные, анимации на сцене зависают. Точно так же при скачивании файла с сервера. Можно как-то избавиться от этого?

Comment: Всё логично. В вашем случае пока данные из интернет не прочитаются (не отработают все readLine) управление сцене передано не будет. Вызывайте механизмы работы с интернет (как и другие тяжелые процессы) в другом потоке. И сообщайте вызывающему главному потоку о результатах, как только операция будет завершена. Ключевые слова для поиска `java async io`. Смотрите тут: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_io/1050__Java_nio_Asynchronous.htm

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Решил. Создал отдельный Thread для запросов к серверу, сделал ему setDeamon(true).